# Perform client-side cell validation JQGrid

Tags: jquery, validation, jqgrid, large-data

I have a bulk of data in my JQgrid, which has almost upto 50 columns. The problem that I face now is that I have to perform validate operation on each cell of the grid.

The validate operations are as follows:

- Length checks
- Formatting checks
- Semantic checks

Secondly, duplicate checks of a particular column, which is currently done is O(n2).

I am also importing data from excel into the grid. In which case, the number of rows can be large...

The instance halts, if number of rows in the grid are more than 200, the performance degrades eventually.

Can anybody come up with a better solution in this regard or a technique to enhance the time complexity.